# Serving static files in Meteor.js

Tags: html, css, meteor

I have custom images and fonts in my Meteor.js application, and I cannot seem to server them.

App:

- .meteor
- image
  -- all images
- fonts -- all fonts
- style.css

In style.css

```css
  background-image: url("image/1.jpg"); - not working
or this
  background-image: url("/image/1.jpg"); - not working
```

What am I doing wrong? Meteor version si 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your images inside a folder called 'public'. You can still make your own folder structure in there, for instance by making a folder 'images' inside public:

```
background-image: url("images/1.jpg");
```

I haven't used special fonts yet so I'm not entirely sure, but I can imagine that you should also put your fonts there.

Note: If you want files to only be available on the server you should put them in a folder called 'private'. These folders aren't made automatically because some people might not need to display any images, fonts or similar things.